# How can I validate non-model properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In my application, I'm dynamically rendering a UI based on runtime data.  There's a model, but it has no compiled properties.  Instead, I'm checking a database and rendering multiple fields using helpers like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("name", RunTimeValue)
```

Now I'd like to include validation on these fields, but I can't see how to do that.  A custom MetadataProvider doesn't seem to work, because this still expects the model to *have* properties, while the provider provides the attributes.  But my model properties simply don't exist until runtime.  I also can't use, e.g., `EditorFor` for this reason.  So how can I inject validation (client and server) into this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have unobstrusive validation enabled, you could cheat by doing this

```
@Html.TextBox("name", RunTimeValue, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "The name is required" } })
```

The other possible data-val values out of the box are data-val-regex (with data-val-regex-pattern), data-val-range (with data-val-range-min and data-val-range-max), data-val-number and some others that I've not used.

Comment: Right, but then I'd have to do all the work to populate those values.  I'm trying to hook into the MVC logic, so it can do this work for me.

Comment: Also this wouldn't handle server side validation.

Comment: @NickLarsen: that's also true, so I'd have to do that manually too.

Comment: Jeow Li Huan: in the end, your suggestion turned out to be not so hard, so I did it that way, with some helper methods so I could reuse the validations almost as easily as the built in ones.  And @NickLarsen, I had to build the server validations too.  Annoying, but in the end faster than beating my head against this problem much longer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery Validation method client side Validation, like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("form").validate({
              rules: {
                  name: "required"
              }
          });
      }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are your constraints?

Are the constraints on the db itself, like max length for strings, null or not, etc?  In that case, you can load the column types from the db and build tools that generate validations from that.  If you are generating the model per request, you can also generate the validation attributes at runtime.   You will probably have to load the model + constraints first, write your own binding logic to update the model with the submitted values, then run validation against it.

Are the constraints in your code?  If this is the case you just need to map the fields loaded at runtime to your in code constraints.

Comment: The constraints are standard things like Length or IsRequired, and I'm happy to emit these in the view based on configuration data in the app.  My question is purely about implementation: In my example, if I know I want a field to have a certain length, be required, etc., how do I attach the validation to the TextBox helper call.  I know that I could go completely manual and build html attributes and call the TextBox overload to include those attributes, but I'm trying to hook into the existing system so I don't have to do all of this manually (and no doubt introduce errors).

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for something like the WebForms validation, where you plunk a RequiredFieldValidator on the form, and tell it what field it's validating, except that I want to stay in the MVC paradigm and let MVC do that work for me.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank How are you building `RunTimeValue`?  If you're rolling up a new class at runtime with reflection, you can just as easily apply `DataAnnotations` attributes to the properties of your class as you build it and it will use all of the magic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  My class represents a table in a database.  The same class is used for all tables in the system. At runtime, I create a Table object for each table in the system, and configure it by specifying the columns (Id, Name, Salary, etc.), but these aren't properties of the Table object, they're added at runtime.  Also at runtime, I generate an Edit screen for a given table, and emit one field for each column in the table.  Each field is just an input element, but some of them are required (non-null), some are specific data types (integer), etc.

Comment: continued: So the question is: for each field, I know what the validation rules are, but I don't know how to render the corresponding input field with the appropriate validation decorations.

Comment: What is the type of RunTimeValue?  What does it look like?  If you're building it at run time, how are you building it?

Comment: Each column has a data type discovered at runtime (integer, string, etc.).  The value is obtained by loading a row from the table of interest, and extracting the data value for a given column.  But in the Create screen, the value might be blank, because it hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank You've basically built your own custom OMF. You're going to have to figure out how to integrate `DataAnnotations` attributes into your OMF. Either that or build your own custom validation implementation to go with your custom OMF.

Comment: I realize that.  My question is: how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

client-side, rigging up jQuery.validate seems best.

server-side, you'll need to query the same source to construct the list of fields, then look through the post variables for each of those fields, validate as needed, and on failure, add to some irrelevant summary string.  This isn't very MVC-ish.

Better: build some model that accounts for this, even if it was IEnumerable where MyFields is:

```
public class MyFields {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    // TODO: Add fields for validation expectations: required, string length, etc
    // TODO: Maybe consider adding fields to specify the control needed: checkbox, select, etc
}
```

If you have a Model like this, server validation on post is just looping through the model ensuring each expected field is present and that each field passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have unobstrusive validation enabled
2. change your control by adding these values like the example

   `@Html.TextBox("name", RunTimeValue, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "The name is required" } })`
3. add this line right after your control

   `@Html.ValidationMessage("name", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`
4. make sure to include the JQuery validation resources

   `@section Scripts {@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}`